# matching links containing part of URL and specific classes

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

There is a web page with different links on this page. My goal is to find links that contain the following: `/dir/flowers/` and have class: `flower big`

and style them differently (ie. make these links red color).

Here are the example links that should match:

```
<a class="flower big" href="http://example.net/dir/flowers/spring.php">Spring</a> 
<a class="flower big" href="http://example.net/dir/flowers/winter.php">Winter</a>    
<a class="flower big" href="http://example.net/dir/flowers/fall.php">Fall</a>
```

etc.

So if a link contains: `/dir/flowers/{*}`  **and** has class:`"flower big"` then it should be matched.

I tried something like below but it's not working:

```css
(a[class="flower big"] AND a[href~="/dir/flowers/"] ) {color:red}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use 2 [CSS attribute selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors)

1. `[class^="flower big"]` with the `^` will look for any element with an attribute name of class and whose first value is prefixed by "flower big".
2. `[href*="/dir/flowers/"]` with `*` which will look for any  `a` with an attribute name of href and whose value contains at least one occurrence of string "/dir/flowers" as substring.

---

```css
a {
  display: block
}
[class^="flower big"][href*="/dir/flowers/"] {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<a class="flower big" href="http://example.net/dir/flowers/spring.php">Will be red because has both classes in order and /dir/flowers/</a>
<a class="flower big" href="http://example.net/dir/flowers/winter.php">Will be red because has both classes in order and /dir/flowers/</a>
<a class="flower big" href="http://example.net/dir/flowers/fall.php">Will be red because has both classes in order and /dir/flowers/</a>
<a class="plant big" href="http://example.net/dir/flowers/spring.php">Won't be red because hasn't classes in order even having  the /dir/flowers/</a>
<a class="flower big" href="http://example.net/dir/foobar/fall.php">Won't be red because hasn't the /dir/flowers/ even having the correct classes</a>
```

---

**UPDATE**

If by any chance you want to have  more classes inside that `a` or change the order of those 2 classes then you need to select the `a` in CSS differently, something like `.flower.big` or `.big.flower` will do it.

```css
a {
  display: block
}
.big.flower[href*="/dir/flowers/"] {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<a class="flower big foobar" href="http://example.net/dir/flowers/spring.php">Will be red because has both classes in link and /dir/flowers/</a>
<a class="big flower" href="http://example.net/dir/flowers/winter.php">Will be red because has both classes in link and /dir/flowers/</a>
<a class="foo bar classes big flower" href="http://example.net/dir/flowers/fall.php">Will be red because has both classes in link and /dir/flowers/</a>
<a class="plant big" href="http://example.net/dir/flowers/spring.php">Won't be red because hasn't classes in link  even having  the /dir/flowers/</a>
<a class="flower big" href="http://example.net/dir/foobar/fall.php">Won't be red because hasn't the /dir/flowers/ even having the correct classes</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```css
.flower.big[href*="dir/flowers"]{
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<a class="flower big" href="http://example.net/dir/flowers/spring.php">Spring</a>

<a class="flower big" href="http://example.net/dir/flowers/winter.php">Winter</a>

<a class="flower big" href="http://example.net/dir/flowers/fall.php">Fall</a>

<a class="flower big" href="http://example.net/dir/other/fall.php">other</a>

<a class="otherClass otherClass" href="http://example.net/dir/other/fall.php">other too</a>
```

`"*="` means "match the following value (**dir/flowers** in this case) anywhere in the attribute value *(**href** in this case)*"

Comment: This will select e.g. "somedir/flowers2" too witch may not be wanted. Better: "/dir/flowers/"